# DFS Replicating files but not deleting the ones removed

Tags: windows, replication, dfs

I have 2 production environment File servers. When setting up DFS, 1 was set as primary and the other as secondary. While Replication process is working, it replicates the newly created files from the primary file server, but it doesn't delete the ones that were removed from the primary server.
While this happens, i get a different quota on the disk for both file servers, primary has more free space due to files being deleted, but secondary has less due to not deleting the removed files.
How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your initial replication is finished ? To be sure, you can check in your event journal the event id 2214 which must indicate your initiale replication is correctly finished.

Moreover, to verify the status of your replication, you can lanch this command :

```
C:\Windows\system32>dfsradmin membership list /rgname:zso-pref87-dfs-rep /attr:IsPrimary,MembershipGuid,memname
IsPrimary  MembershipGuid                        MemName
No         49dddd99-fdd3-dddd-dddd-dzdzdzdzdzdz  SERVER2
No         sdsdsdsd-ffff-ssss-ssss-sdsddsddsdsd  SERVER1
```

Until your initial replication will not finished, you won't be able to have a operational DFS. You can use `robocopy /MIR` before the initiale replication to accelerate the process.

To verify the state of your replication, you can look at the backlogs, it's the files wich are waiting to be replicated, normally, you would not have more than 100 files in staying state :

```
dfsrdiag backlog /rgname:<replication name> /rfname:<diretory replicated> /sendingmember:server1 /receivingmember:server2 /v
```